# MySQL CASE QUERY with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table with string type. (photo_add, photo_comment etc.)
Then I have 4 other tables that are connected with these types.

I need to make a query which will choose the data from all these tables according to the type.

I created this but it does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.event, a.params, a.created_at, a.item_id, a.sender_id, a.receiver_id, u.name, u.id as userid 
FROM `eva49_lovefactory_activity` a, eva49_users u 
CASE a.event 
  WHEN "photo_add" THEN 
    INNER JOIN eva49_lovefactory_photos lp ON lp.id = a.item_id AND lp.fsk18 = -1
  WHEN "group_create" THEN 
     INNER JOIN eva49_lovefactory_groups lg ON lg.id = a.item_id AND lg.fsk18 = -1 
  WHEN "photo_comment" THEN 
     INNER JOIN eva49_lovefactory_item_comments lic ON lic.item_id = a.item_id AND lic.fsk18 = -1 
  WHEN "profile_comment" THEN 
     INNER JOIN eva49_lovefactory_item_comments lic ON lic.item_id = a.item_id AND lic.fsk18 = -1 
  WHEN "profile_comment" THEN 
    INNER JOIN eva49_lovefactory_profiles lp ON lp.user_id = a.receiver_id AND lp.status_fsk18 = -1 
  ELSE 1=1 
END 
WHERE (u.id = a.sender_id OR u.id = a.receiver_id) and (u.id <> 379) 
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is there any way how to pair the tables? The database structure was given to me like this.

EDIT:

There is a table "eva49_lovefactory_activity" which contains information about recent activity. It has a column "event" that contains string with the event name (photo_add, photo_comment etc.)

There are other tables - eva49_lovefactory_photos, eva49_lovefactory_profiles, eva49_lovefactory_groups etc. In these tables I have to find whether the item was approved by admin. If it was I can show it. (fsk18 = -1)

Comment: As far as I am aware, You cannot join tables with a CASE. I stand corrected though...

Comment: Your query has many syntactical issues and I not able to make assumption to your intention. Can you explain what you intended to do?

Comment: I edited task. I hope it helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Even if it were possible to do contingent joins: If you don't know beforehand which table will be joined, you cannot use its columns. So why join at all? What data do you actually want to retrieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move CASE condition to JOIN condition and do LEFT JOIN..

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.event, a.params, a.created_at, a.item_id, a.sender_id, a.receiver_id, u.name, u.id as userid 
FROM `eva49_lovefactory_activity` a, eva49_users u 

    LEFT JOIN eva49_lovefactory_photos lp ON lp.id = a.item_id AND lp.fsk18 = -1
               AND a.event='photo_add'
    LEFT JOIN eva49_lovefactory_groups lg ON lg.id = a.item_id AND lg.fsk18 = -1 
               AND a.event='group_create'
    LEFT JOIN eva49_lovefactory_item_comments lic ON lic.item_id = a.item_id AND 
              lic.fsk18 = -1     AND a.event='photo_comment'
    LEFT JOIN eva49_lovefactory_item_comments lic ON lic.item_id = a.item_id AND 
              lic.fsk18 = -1     AND   a.event='profile_comment'

WHERE (u.id = a.sender_id OR u.id = a.receiver_id) and (u.id <> 379) 
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: There could be a problem that I can have 1 item that could accidentally fulfill 2 JOINs and then I will not get correct results. Am I right?

Comment: Since a.event contains only one value and it is used in ON clause with AND condition , only one of the JOIN conditions will evalute to be true .

Comment: My bad. I did not see the last AND with a.event.